# Entity Framework inserting long value instead of actual string value to database for my ASP.NET core site

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

My Entity Framework passes a string like this to the database "1b2ef80d-038a-49d8-973b-fc783a53b6a3" instead of the text i placed into the input field, which was "text".  How can i only Insert the exact value into the table?

The Database table i'm currently testing is just one column and is set to VARCHAR(400).

Context class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Contract1)
                    .HasName("Contract$PrimaryKey");

                entity.Property<string>(e => e.Contract1)
                    .HasColumnName("Contract")
                    .HasColumnType("VARCHAR(400)")
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasMaxLength(400);
            });
```

Model class:

```
     [Key]
            [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(400)")]
            [StringLength(400)]
            public string Contract1 { get; set; }
```

View page:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Contract</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contract1, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contract1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contract1)
                <span class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
</body>
</html>
```

And Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Contract")] Contract Contract)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(Contract);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }
            ViewData["Contract"] = new SelectList(_context.Contract, "Contract", "Contract", Contract.Contract1);
            return View(Contract);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had to add the class, instead of just the context.Add i had to make it context.class.Add:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Contract Contract)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Contract.Add(Contract);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewData["Contract"] = new SelectList(_context.Contract, "Contract", "Contract", Contract.Contract1);
            return View(Contract);
        }
    }
}
```